# Java changes multiple values at once

Tags: java

I really don't like asking these kinds of questions and this is probably a duplicate, but i am really stuck on this and because i am new to java (not to programming in general) i can't figure it out.

The problem is as follows: The array `names` should be sorted, and i came up with the following code:

```
String[] temp_names = names;

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < names.length; j++)
        {
            String biggest = ""+(0);
            int biggest_index = 0;

            for (int chr = 0; chr < ((biggest.length() < temp_names[j].length()) ? biggest.length() : temp_names[j].length()); chr++)
            {
                if (biggest.toCharArray()[chr] > temp_names[j].toCharArray()[chr])
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (biggest.toCharArray()[chr] < temp_names[j].toCharArray()[chr])
                {
                    biggest = temp_names[j];
                    biggest_index = j;
                    break;
                }
            }

            names[i] = biggest;
            temp_names[biggest_index] = ""+(255);
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs at the last line. I set the value to as high as possible so when sorting it is basically ignored (it will always come last). The problem is that when `temp_names[biggest_index]` is set to '255', `biggest` is also set to 255 which in turn sets `names[i]` to 255. This leaves me with an array full of empty names.

I know this has something to do with that java copys the variable as a reference instead of as a value, but when i try to copy/clone it by using `names[i] = new String(biggest)` it still has the same result. I've tried many different things and now i've run out of ideas so i hope someone here can help.

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Harm

-Edit:
This is an exercise for school so i can't just use standard java functions.

Comment: `Arrays.sort(names);`

Comment: Arrays.sort(args);

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ slowpoke ;-)

Comment: Harm Prins, next time please read the Java API before posting, most common functionality has already been programmed.

Comment: String[] temp_names = names; This line makes temp_names and names point to the same array. If this works I will post the answer

Comment: `I know this has something to do with that java copys the variable as a reference`, well you´re working with `String`'s here which are immutable and as so they don´t copy any reference here.

Comment: @domdom this is obviously an exercise or school project. Arrays.sort() defeats the purpose.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider it might, it might not. We'll only know if OP tells us.

Comment: As Christopher pointed out, this is indeed an excercise for school

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SOCLass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] names = new String[] {"joe", "bill"};
        String[] temp_names  = names;// new String[names.length];
        //System.arraycopy(names, 0, temp_names, 0, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < names.length; j++)
            {
                String biggest = ""+(0);
                int biggest_index = 0;

                for (int chr = 0; chr < ((biggest.length() < temp_names[j].length()) ? biggest.length() : temp_names[j].length()); chr++)
                {
                    if (biggest.toCharArray()[chr] > temp_names[j].toCharArray()[chr])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (biggest.toCharArray()[chr] < temp_names[j].toCharArray()[chr])
                    {
                        biggest = temp_names[j];
                        biggest_index = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                names[i] = biggest;
                temp_names[biggest_index] = ""+(255);
            }
        }

        for(String s : names)
            System.out.println(s);
        for(String s : temp_names)
            System.out.println(s);

    }

}
```

This is the code as you wrote it. It prints out 255 on both. Comment in the new String[...] and System.arraycopy(...) and it prints bill the longest/biggest.

By not allocating a new array, temp_names and names are the same. Changes in one reflect on the other

Comment: Ah i get it, so it doesn't copy the value in the way i thought it did, but via the first line of the code. Thanks!